# Modify this IPv6 to Binary statement to deal with more than two consecutive sections of zeroes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm using SQL 2005. I'm hoping someone can help me modify this statement so that it can handle more than one consecutive sections of zeroes. This statement converts IPv6 addresses to binary.

Lets say you have this IPv6 address: 2001:db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:370:7334.

It can be re-written as 2001:db8:85a3::8a2e:370:7334 to get rid of the consecutive sections of zeroes.

However, the below SQL statement can only deal with the above IPv6 address if it is written in full notation as 2001:db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:370:7334, to give me a binary result of 0x20010DB885A3000000008A2E03707334.

How can the below statement be modified so that I can deal with the IPv6 address written as 2001:db8:85a3::8a2e:370:7334? Or even an address such as ::1?

```
DECLARE    @ipstr VARCHAR(50)
SET        @ipstr = '2001:db8:85a3::0000:8a2e:370:7334'
SELECT     CAST('' AS XML).value('xs:hexBinary( sql:column("y.ips") )', 'varbinary(16)')
FROM       (
            SELECT ips = (
                          SELECT  RIGHT('0000' + SUBSTRING(ips, NUMBER, CHARINDEX(':', ips, NUMBER) - NUMBER), 4)
                          FROM    master.dbo.spt_values
                                 ,(SELECT ips = ':' + @ipstr + ':') x
                          WHERE   TYPE = 'P'
                                  AND NUMBER BETWEEN 2 AND LEN(ips)
                                  AND SUBSTRING(ips, NUMBER-1, 1) = ':'
                          FOR     XML PATH('')
                         )
           ) y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably isn't the cleanest solution, but it works:

```
WITH cteRawSections (RowNumber, ips) As
(
   -- Split the address into sections:
   SELECT
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY number),
      Substring(ips, number, CharIndex(':', ips, number) - number)
   FROM
      master.dbo.spt_values
      CROSS APPLY
      (SELECT ips = ':' + @ipstr + ':') As c
   WHERE
      type = 'P'
   And
      number Between 2 And Len(ips)
   And
      Substring(ips, number - 1, 1) = ':'
),
cteSections (RowNumber, ips) As
(
   -- Pad the non-empty sections:
   SELECT
      RowNumber,
      Right('0000' + ips, 4)
   FROM
      cteRawSections
   WHERE
      ips != ''

   UNION ALL

   -- Include the missing sections:
   SELECT
      (SELECT Min(RowNumber) FROM cteRawSections WHERE ips = ''),
      '0000'
   FROM
      master.dbo.spt_values
   WHERE
      type = 'P'
   And
      number >= 1
   And
      number <= (SELECT 8 - Count(1) FROM cteRawSections WHERE ips != '')
),
cteJoined As
(
   -- Join the sections in order:
   SELECT ips = 
   (
      SELECT ips
      FROM cteSections
      ORDER BY RowNumber
      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
   ).value('.', 'varchar(max)')
)
SELECT
   CAST('' As XML).value('xs:hexBinary(sql:column("y.ips"))', 'varbinary(16)')
FROM
   cteJoined As y
;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/7258/0

**NB:** Your sample address, `2001:db8:85a3:0000:0000:0000:8a2e:370:7334`, is too long to be a valid IPv6 address.

Comment: That's awesome, yes it does. Is there any way of modifying this code so that I can use it as part of a select statement in a view? So as part of the SELECT, I have a column called [IPAddress]. After that I have a column called [IPBinary] and this column has a CASE statement set up so that a IPv4 address gets converted to binary and the second part of the CASE would convert IPv6 addresses to binary. I'm not sure how I could integrate the above code into my select as we currently have to do a DECLARE/SET for the IPAddress and you can't do that in a SELECT. Any suggestions?

Comment: Would it be possible to set this up as an in line table valued function that I can use in my SELECT?

Comment: @user1367200: Yes, you just need to wrap the query in a suitable `CREATE FUNCTION` block. For example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/11ead/1/0

Comment: Thanks! It seems really obvious now that you've pointed it out, but it probably would have taken a couple of hours to figure out the "return table" part of the function. Appreciate the help, this is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Insert this after your Set @ipstr statement:

```
    declare @colonCount int = len(@ipstr)-len(replace(@ipstr,':',''))
    if(@colonCount<7)
        set @ipstr=replace(@ipstr,'::', replicate( ':0',7-@colonCount+1) +':')
```